# How to add days to current date in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

In clojure I want to add days to current date can anyone please guide me on that. Am getting current date as below and now let's say I want to add 7 days to it, how can I get a new date?

```
(.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "MM/dd/yyyy") (java.util.Date.))
```

Answer (score 7):

This would work:

```
(java.util.Date. (+ (* 7 86400 1000) (.getTime (java.util.Date.)))
```

I prefer to use `System/currentTimeMillis` for the current time:

`(java.util.Date. (+ (* 7 86400 1000) (System/currentTimeMillis)))`

Or you can use `clj-time` which is a nicer api to deal with time (it's a wrapper around Joda Time). From the readme file:

`(t/plus (t/date-time 1986 10 14) (t/months 1) (t/weeks 3))`

`=> #<DateTime 1986-12-05T00:00:00.000Z>`

Comment: This is wrong! You should never assume that a day always has 86400 seconds in it. If you are crossing the boundary of DST you will be will be either getting an extra hour or losing an extra hour.

Comment: Ex: (.format  (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm z") (java.util.Date. (+ (* 7 86400 1000) (.getTime (.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm z") "2015/03/05 00:00 PDT"))))) produces "2015/03/11 23:00 GMT-08:00", not "2015/03/12 00:00 GMT -0:8:00" as desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
user> (import '[java.util Calendar])
;=> java.util.Calendar
user> (defn days-later [n]
        (let [today (Calendar/getInstance)]
          (doto today
            (.add Calendar/DATE n)
            .toString)))
#'user/days-later
user> (println "Tomorrow: " (days-later 1))
;=> Tomorrow:  #inst "2014-11-26T15:36:31.901+09:00"
;=> nil
user> (println "7 Days from now: " (days-later 7))
;=> 7 Days from now:  #inst "2014-12-02T15:36:44.785+09:00"
;=> nil
```