# How do I add days to a date in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clj-time

I have looked at the following question: 
[How to add days to current date in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27115640/how-to-add-days-to-current-date-in-clojure).

However I am very new to Clojure and I am getting stuck on the following scenario I am getting the timestamp in string format. So I am parsing it using the following:

```
(.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") date)
```

Which gives me a result that looks like this:

```
#inst "2015-02-13T00:20:00.000-00:00"
```

How do I add say 90 days to this and then convert it back to string format? I tried this based on the above link:

```
(java.util.Date. (+ (* 7 86400 1000) 
                    (.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") date)))
```

Which gave me the following error:

```
ClassCastException java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.add
```

Comment: It's better to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) instead of the default Java date/time libraries. There is a Clojure wrapper available as well, [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time). See this [IBM Developer Works article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jodatime/index.html#N100BA) for details on why Joda Time is the better option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`parse` returns a `java.util.Date`, the error you are seeing is telling you that you can't cast a `Date` to a `Number`. You can use `getTime` to get the milliseconds of a `Date`:

```
(java.util.Date. (+ (* 7 86400 1000)
                 (.getTime (.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") date))))
```

This *potentially* adds 7 days to the date. If you want to *potentially* add 90 days you need to replace the 7 with 90, like this: `(* 90 86400 1000)`.

You can also use `java.util.Calendar`:

```
(let [cal (Calendar/getInstance)
      d (.parse (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "yyyy-MM-dd") date)]
  (doto cal
    (.setTime d)
    (.add Calendar/DATE 90)
    (.getTime)))
```

Or better yet, [clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time):

```
(require '[clj-time.core :as t])
(require '[clj-time.format :as f])

(t/plus (f/parse (f/formatters :year-month-day) date)
        (t/days 90))
```

Comment: Ohh sorry about the 7 and 90 days thing. That was a typo.

Comment: "This adds 7 days to the date" --- if only every of those is exactly `86400` seconds, which is not always the case

Comment: Yes +1 for clj-time. I had to do something similar a while back and initially did it using native java methods. It worked fine, but had a lot of messy code. Re-wrote it when I found out about clj-time and now its much smaller and easier to understand. Dates and Times has always been a PITA in java

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn’t recommend using the legacy date and time API in new code if you can avoid it.

Java 8 brought a new API for dates with which you can express this problem elegantly:

```
(let [date-format java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter/ISO_LOCAL_DATE]
  (.. (java.time.LocalDate/parse "2015-02-13" date-format)
      (plusDays 90)
      (format date-format)))
```

Or even, taking all shortcuts:

```
(-> (java.time.LocalDate/parse "2015-02-13") (.plusDays 90) str)
```

Answer (score 3):

[clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) has **`from-now`** and **`ago`**:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :refer [days from-now]])

(-> 90 days from-now)
```

`=> #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x4d8bcee3 "2017-01-11T16:03:40.067Z"]`

```
(require '[clj-time.core :refer [hours ago]])

(-> 7 hours ago)
```

`=> #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x3eef2142 "2016-10-13T09:19:01.246Z"]`

Available **`PeriodType`** definitions: `years`, `months`, `weeks`, `days`, `hours`, `minutes`, `seconds`.

---

The resulting Joda `DateTime` objects can easily be manipulated, for instance to a  unix epoch in milliseconds:

```
(require '[clj-time.core :refer [days from-now]])
(require '[clj-time.coerce :as coerce])

(coerce/to-long (-> 90 days from-now))
```

`=> 1484150620067`

Answer (score 0):

This solution returns a `java.util.Date`:

```
(defn add-days-to-instant [num-days ^java.util.Date d]
  (.getTime (let [cal (Calendar/getInstance)]
              (doto cal
                (.setTime d)
                (.add Calendar/DATE num-days)))))
```